# Excel Text to Date format

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I wish to convert the text string, (which in imported into excel as a 'General' formatted field) 12/31/2017 into date format displaying it as; dd/mm/yyyy, however all attempts have failed so far, incl. the text to columns option, reformatting it as a date field using English (UK) as the Locale.

I have also tried to parse the text using a formula based on the: DATE, LEFT, MID, and RIGHT Functions; to no avail.  The problem appears to be the inclusion of the / in the text string and the fact that I wish to swap around the format from mm/dd/yyyy to dd/mm/yyyy. Anyone out there experienced this issue?

Comment: I also at times have massive issues  with this. Does this help? https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/Format-a-date-the-way-you-want-8e10019e-d5d8-47a1-ba95-db95123d273e

Comment: Thanks Dave, but sadly not tried there, default is already set to [$-en-GB]dd mmmm yyyy, changing it to something like dd/mm/yyyy, still displays the 'date' as 12/31/2017 ! Don't you just love excel?

Comment: Yes, this issue is very easy to replicate but very hard to fix. I assume your machine's locale is set for UK?

Comment: How are you **importing** the data?  You should be able to set, in the Text Import Wizard (similar to the Text to columns wizard), the date format.  Be sure to set it to `MDY` (the format of the incoming data).  If that is not creating a real date, that you can reformat, perhaps you could upload a copy of a file that reproduces the problem.  The TTC wizard is pretty smart, and should have no problem with your data as you show it, unless there is something quite odd about the data, or your environment.

Answer (score 2):

With *Text* in **A1**, in **B1** enter:

```
=DATE(RIGHT(A1,4),LEFT(A1,FIND("/",A1)-1),TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE($A1,"/",REPT(" ",999)),2*999-998,999)))
```

and apply the proper format:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I just confirmed Dave's hunch on my own computer, that the machine's clock settings not only affect Excel, they *limit* Excel's ability to understand dates other than the computer's clock format.

Personally, I set my Windows clock to display dd-mm-yy though I am in the U.S. So when I enter "12/31/2017" Excel cannot fathom that this is a date no matter what I try. Changing the number format to either Short Date, Long Date, or Number makes no difference, it's still a string. Subjecting it to functions like DATEVALUE(), VALUE(), or TEXT("12/31/2017","dd/mm/yyyy") returns a #VALUE! error.

But just so I don't leave you with nothing, I put together a not-so-pretty but working formula to apply to your cells:

where

```
A1 ="12/31/2017"
A2 =LEFT(A1,FIND("/",A1)-1) [month]
A3 =MID(A1,FIND("/",A1)+1,(FIND("/",A1,FIND("/",A1)+1))-(FIND("/",A1)+1)) [day]
A4 =RIGHT(A1,4) [year]
```

you would concatenate like

```
=CONCATENATE(A3,"/",A2,"/",A4)
```

for a grand total formula of

```
=CONCATENATE(MID(A1,FIND("/",A1)+1,(FIND("/",A1,FIND("/",A1)+1))-(FIND("/",A1)+1)),"/",LEFT(A1,FIND("/",A1)-1),"/",RIGHT(A1,4))
```